# insert new record between records and update next all records by +1

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to insert a new record between records and update all next records by one
like

```
1   aaa   450
2   bbb   550
3   ccc   780
4   ddd   745
```

I want to insert record at position 3 and in form I will put id = 3 and then the next records will be updated by +1.

Like when I insert 3 then the no. 3 record will be 4 and no. 4 record will be 5

I have done this by these codes in SQL Server 2008

```
UPDATE Testing 
SET id = id + 1 
WHERE id >= 3 

INSERT INTO Testing (id, CName, Value) 
VALUES (3, 'ddd', 589)

SELECT * 
FROM Testing 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

and it is working in SQL SeErver 2008

I want this happen with asp.net application and here is what I am going nuts.

Please help me !!

Comment: So what is your problem? You can execute any SQL statement from C# code using `SqlCommand` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C# code in your web Application

```
    string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            //Create the SqlCommand object
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddNumber", con);
            //Specify that the SqlCommand is a stored procedure
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //Add the input parameters to the command object
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "3");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", "ddd");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "589");


            //Open the connection and execute the query
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And Your StoredProcedure. When Add this StoredProcedure check the length of CName

```
Create Procedure spAddNumber
@id int,
@CName nvarchar(10),
@Value int
as
Begin
UPDATE Testing SET id = id + 1 WHERE id >= 3 
insert into Testing (id,CName ,Value ) values (@id ,@CName ,@Value )

End
```

if you are going to use Sqlcommand directly

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Your Query Here", connection);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```